# duplicate entry 0 for key primary

Tags: mysql

Tengo esta tabla [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La he creado sin ningún tipo de problemas, pero a la hora de insertar jugadores, me da problemas al intentar insertar el segundo con duplicate entry 0 for key primary. ACLARAR QUE DESPUÉS DE CREAR LAS TABLAS PUSE COMO PRIMARYKEY TAMBIEN EL IDVISITANTE DE LA TABLA ACTA (debido a que el código que os voy a poner no tengo puesto esta como primary key)

Os dejo como he creado la tabla

```
create table club (
  idclub int,
  nombre varchar(20),
  presupuesto int,
  njnac int,
  njext int,
  gfavor int,
  gcontra int,
  PRIMARY KEY(idclub)
) Engine = Innodb;

create table club (
  idclub int primary key,
  idvisitante int,
  jornada int,
  goles_club int,
  goles_vis int,
  PRIMARY KEY(idclub, idvisitante)
) Engine = Innodb;

create table jugador (
  idjugador int primary key,
  idclub int,
  nombre varchar(20),
  nacionalidad varchar(20),
  sueldo varchar(20),
  PRIMARY KEY(idjugador)
) Engine = Innodb;

create table privilegiados (
  idjugador int,
  PRIMARY KEY(idjugador)
) Engine = Innodb;
```

Comment: Y como haces la insercion?

Comment: insert into jugador values( 2,2,"Messi","Argentino",7000000 )

Comment: ya existe un club que tenga el id 2?

Comment: Hay 4 clubes y ninguno tiene el id 0, lo tienen del 1 al 4

Comment: Por qué no dejas los Id´s como `AUTO_INCREMENT` y dejas que el sistema lo haga solo?

Comment: y que insercion hiciste antes de esa?